# Completely multiplicative and square-summable sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I have the following statement.

Suppose $(a_n)$ is a sequence of complex numbers satisfying the following properties.

i) $a_{nm} = a_na_m$ for all positive integers $n, m$.

ii)
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \geq 1} |a_n|^2 < \infty. 
\end{align}

iii) Not all $a_n$ are zero.

Then $|a_n| \leq n^{-1/2}$ for all positive integers $n$.

I have 3 questions that are all related.

1. Is the statement true?
2. I have a proof that I think is correct using Hilbert space theory. Is there a quick elementary proof?
3. How could this statement be generalised to the case of an arbitrary locally compact, Hausdorff abelian group?

Edit: noticed a flaw in my proof from a counterexample in the comments. Fixed my proof and replaced $1/n$ by $n^{-1/2}$.

Comment: $a_n=1/n^{3/4}?$

Comment: @user469053 i see the problem. i guess i must have made a mistake somewhere... thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Given statement (i), statement (ii) is *equivalent* to
$$
\text{(ii')} \quad |a_p| < 1 \text{ for all primes } p, \text{ and } \sum_p |a_p|^2 \text{ converges.}
$$
The reason is that when we have a convergent series with a completely multiplicative function, it can always be written as an Euler product
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^2 = \prod_p \bigl( 1 + |a_p|^2 + |a_{p^2}|^2 + \cdots \bigr) = \prod_p \bigl( 1 - |a_p|^2 \bigr)^{-1}.
$$

In particular, the bound $|a_n| \le n^{-1/2}$ is not necessarily true, nor is $|a_n| \le n^{-\varepsilon}$ for any $\varepsilon>0$, because we can choose any finite number of primes to "misbehave". For example, if
$$
a_p = \begin{cases}
0.99, &\text{if } p=2, \\
1/p, &\text{if } p\ge3,
\end{cases}
$$
then $a_{2^k} = 0.99^k = (2^k)^{-\log(1/0.99)/log 2} \approx (2^k)^{-0.0145}$, far greater than $(2^k)^{-1/2}$; and the exponent $0.0145$ can be made arbitrarily close to $0$ by moving the $0.99$ closer to $1$.

Comment: I agree that we must have $|a_p| < 1$, for example by comparing the sum $\sum_{k \geq 1} |a_{p^k}|^2$ with $\sum_{n \geq 1} |a_n|^2$, but why can't we have a bound of the form $|a_n| \leq n^{-\varepsilon}$ for any fixed $\varepsilon > 0$? For example $a_n = 1/n$ satisfies all of the hypotheses and has a bound of this form with $\varepsilon = 1$.

Comment: I didn't say such a bound was impossible—I said it wasn't necessarily true.

Comment: Ah I see thank you. I should have read your answer more thoroughly :)

Comment: @JosephHarrison I corrected and clarified this answer in response to your recent critique.

Comment: Your counterexample does indeed seem to work. In fact we can replace $0.99$ with any $1/\sqrt{2} = 0.707\dots < \delta < 1$. I will have to figure out what went wrong with my proof.

Answer (score 0):

I am including my proof here. Perhaps someone can find an error.

For each positive integer $m$, define an operator
\begin{align}
T_m : L^2(\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z}) &\to L^2(\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z}) \\
(T_mg)(x) &=
\frac{1}{m}\sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1}
g\Big(\frac{x + j}{m}\Big).
\end{align}
By hypothesis (ii) on $(a_n)$, the function
\begin{align}
f(x) = \sum_{n \geq 1} a_n\exp(2\pi i nx)
\end{align}
is in $L^2(\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z})$. We also have
\begin{align}
(T_mf)(x) &= \frac{1}{m}\sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1} \sum_{n \geq 1} a_n
\exp\Big(\frac{2\pi in(x + j)}{m}\Big) \\
&= \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n\exp\Big(\frac{2\pi inx}{m}\Big)
\sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1}\exp\Big(\frac{2\pi i nj}{m}\Big) \\
&=
\sum_{n \geq 1}a_{nm}\exp(2\pi inx)\\
&= a(m)f(x)
\end{align}
where we have used hypothesis (i) on $(a_n)$ in the final line and the fact that
\begin{align}
\sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1}\exp\Big(\frac{2\pi inj}{m}\Big)
=
\begin{cases}
m & m \mid n \\
0 & m \nmid n
\end{cases}
\end{align}
in the penultimate line.

Moreover, for $g \in L^2(\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z})$ we have
\begin{align}
||T_mg||_2^2 &= \int_{\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z}}
\bigg|
\frac{1}{m}\sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1}
g\Big(\frac{x + j}{m}\Big)
\bigg|^2 \, dx \\
&\leq
\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1}
\int_{\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z}}
\Big|
g\Big(\frac{x + j}{m}\Big)
\Big|^2
\, dx \\
&=
\frac{1}{m^2}
\sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1}
\int_{j/m}^{(j + 1)/m}
|g(y)|^2 \, mdy \\
&= \frac{||g||_2^2}{m}.
\end{align}
It now follows that
\begin{align}
|a(m)| \cdot ||f||_2 = ||T_mf||_2 \leq \frac{||f||_2}{\sqrt{m}}
\end{align}
and the desired inequality follows. Note that $||f||_2$ is non-zero because not all $a_n$ are zero.

Comment: One tangible counterexample to the assertion in the OP is $a_n = 0.9^{\Omega(n)}$, where $\Omega(n)$ is the number of prime factors of $n$ counted with multiplicity. (One can use any constant in $(0,1)$ in place of $0.9$.) It might help to go through this proof with that counterexample and see where it breaks down.

Comment: @GregMartin I think that the sequence $a_n = 0.9^{\Omega(n)}$ doesn't satisfy condition (ii) in the statement of the question. For example $\sum_{n \geq 1} |a_n|^2 \geq \sum_{p \textrm{ prime}} c^2$, which doesn't converge.

Comment: Aha, you're right, my argument has overlooked something all along.